# Json sorting using twitter api

Tags: php, json, twitter

Hi I am using twitter api to fetch the tweets using hashtag:and here is the code that is used in js file to append the tweets:

```
$(JQTWEET.appendTo).append( 
    JQTWEET.template.replace('{TEXT}', JQTWEET.ify.clean(data[i].text) )
    .replace('{USER}', data[i].user.screen_name) 
    .replace('{IMG}', img)
    .replace('{AGO}', JQTWEET.timeAgo(data[i].created_at) )
    .replace('{URL}', url)
    .replace('{LIKE}',data[i].retweet_count )
);
```

but i want it sorting order based on retweet count.How could i do this?

Comment: Does jqTweet even still work? I thought it was broken because of Twitters endpoints. Have you looked in the manual yet? I don't think it can sort by itself.

Comment: yes,it can not sort by itself.if i want to sort then how i customize the code?please help me.